# stage.hide() doesn't close window

Tags: spring, javafx, scenebuilder

I have a JavaFX application and I have created a toggle button that pops out a chart into a new (non-modal) window. The button is designed to also pop the chart back into its `VBox` of the main application window. If the new chart window is manually closed, the chart also returns to the original VBox.

In code below is a generic `setOnAction` function (setToggleButton) that I call at initialization for numerous buttons that are associated with their own chart.

For instance:

```java
@Component
public class SummaryView {

    private GraphService graphService;
    @FXML
    private VBox powerChartVBox;
    @FXML
    private LineChart<Number, Number> powerChart;
    @FXML
    private Button openPowerChart;
    @FXML
    private NumberAxis powerAxis;

    public void setButtonToggle(Button button, LineChart<Number, Number> chart, VBox homeBox) {
        var ref = new Object() {
            Boolean popIn = false; // changes to allow toggle
        };

        button.setOnAction(actionEvent -> {
            VBox windowBox = new VBox();
            Stage stage = new Stage();
            Scene scene = new Scene(windowBox);
            stage.setOnCloseRequest(event -> {
                homeBox.getChildren().add(chart);
                ref.popIn = false;
                button.setText("Pop Out");
            });

            if (!ref.popIn){
                windowBox.getChildren().add(chart);
                stage.setScene(scene);
                stage.show();
                ref.popIn = true;
                button.setText("Pop In");
            } else {
                stage.hide(); // how to get this line to work?
                homeBox.getChildren().add(chart);
                ref.popIn = false;
                button.setText("Pop Out");
            }
        });
    }

    @FXML
    public void initialize() {
        graphService = SpringContext.getBean(GraphService.class);

        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            setButtonToggle(openPowerChart, powerChartStage, powerChart, powerChartVBox); 
        // in my application I call this function a few more times on other nodes as well
        });
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 300000)
    private void updateCharts() {
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            XYChart.Series<Number, Number> outputKWSeries = graphService.updateKWOutputSeries();
            XYChart.Series<Number, Number> outputKVSeries = graphService.updateKVOutputSeries();
            XYChart.Series<Number, Number> outputKASeries = graphService.updateKAOutputSeries();
            powerAxis.setUpperBound(graphService.getUpperBound());
            powerAxis.setLowerBound(graphService.getLowerBound(40));
            powerChart.getData().clear();
            powerChart.getData().addAll(outputKWSeries, outputKVSeries, outputKASeries);
    })

}
```

However, the new window I am creating with "pop out" action handler, doesn't close from the toggle button (which changes to "pop in" after the first click and then and uses the second branch of the if/else statement). I have tried various methods but I'm not finding a solution. If I try `scene.getWindow().hide()` it will cause a null pointer exception. What I currently have below will not actually hide the window, just move the chart back to the original position.

This is a screenshot - on the top, you see the blank window that remains when I hit the "Pop In" button.

[image]

So at this moment, everything works as intended, but when I hit the button to "Pop In" the window, the chart returns to its home but the window stays open as a blank window. Closing the window manually with its own X button, however, results in the desired behavior as long as it hasn't already been turned into a blank window by the toggle button, in which case the exception will be:

`Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Children: duplicate children added: parent = VBox[id=powerChartVBox]`

This exception makes sense to me because the `setOnCloseRequest` I called on the stage is trying to add the VBox back to the main application's VBox but it already exists there.

So to summarize, how do I get `stage.hide()` in the first line of my else branch to execute on the stage I initially created, and close the window?

Comment: I believe your problem occurs because you create the stage within the `setOnAction`. When you toggle the button, it creates a new instance of `Stage` and does not affect the stage already instantiated. I would recommend instantiation the `Stage` outside of the `EventHandler`.

Comment: @JulianBroudy yes, I believe you are correct.

Comment: @JulianBroudy do you by any chance have any tips for where to instantiate it? Other places I've tried to move it are not allowing the application to compile because it has to be instantiated on the FX application thread.

Comment: I figured it out... I instantiated it inside of a `platform.runLater` it feels a little hacky, but it works! If you want to answer this question I will accept it.

Comment: You should store the `Stage` in a field and, in the on-action handler, check if the field is null or not and act accordingly.

Comment: Sure, thanks. Glad it worked for you.

Comment: I cannot officially answer your question since it is closed as "Needs details or clarity". Once you edit your question to satisfy the community's guidelines I'd be more than happy to provide you with a more in-depth answer.

Comment: _platform.runLater it feels a little hacky_ if done on the fx application thread, doing so __is__ hacky ;) While there are corner cases, this doesn't look like one of them (hard to tell, as you insist on not providing complete details, best as a [mcve] - your setup looks fishy (why do you even _try_ to share nodes across different windows? typically we share data .. )

Comment: @kleopatra thank you for the link resource. I've been using JavaFX for about a year now but I never had a formal introduction to it so very likely I've picked up some bad habits. I believe what you're suggesting is that instead of trying to move the chart to a new window, just have a separate chart in that window and share the data with it. That would make sense.

Comment: yeah, something like that - but beware: what a chart calls "data" is not shareable because it carries nodes as well as what we would call data ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comments, your problem occurs because you create the stage within the `setOnAction`. 
When you toggle the button, it creates a new instance of `Stage` and does not affect the stage already instantiated.

**To fix this** you should instantiate the `Stage` outside of the `EventHandler`.

**There are several ways to do so:**

```
public class YourController{

  // Option 1
  private Stage newStage = new Stage();

  // Options 2 & 3
  private Stage newStage;

  // Option 2
  public YourController(){
    newStage = new Stage();
  }

  @FXML
  public void initialize() {
    // Option 3
    newStage = new Stage(); 
    // Option 4
    Stage newStage = new Stage();
  }

}
```

Note that manipulating the GUI must occur on the `JavaFX Application Thread` and so if you attempt to do so from another thread, [`platform.runLater();`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-) could come in handy.